# Shader(Effect file) Crashing on Load

Tags: c#, shader, monogame

It worked just fine in the 3.5 stable version, but after upgrading to the lastest  development branch (3.6), it no longer works, giving me this error on `effect = content.Load<Effect>("fileName")`

> An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll
>
> Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: The parameter is incorrect.

Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Well it is a development branch, you generally should expect problems.  Perhaps raise a ticket with the Monogame team?

Comment: A more complete stack trace and the effect source would help in debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
I think the default value has changed GraphicsProfile.
(HiDef -> Reach)
So if you specify it, it got it fixed.

```
Graphics.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.HiDef;
```